# HTML table: remove space between two td tag

Tags: css, html

How I can remove this space from  tag.

```
    <table width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Filename</td>
      <td colspan="2">DateTime</td>
      <td>Size</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr>
      <td>43343434.jpg</td>
      <td>18/02/2015</td>
      <td> - 18:32:54</td>
      <td>55MB</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Image:
[image]

So it looks like 18/02/2015 - 18:32:54

I dont want to add time into same  tag.

Comment: share your html code

Comment: Try 1: make your DateTime column aligned right

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hx6pmrcz/

Comment: Would you please post you HTML code for the same

Comment: Added HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define css:

```
tbody tr > td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 5%;
}
tbody tr > td{
  width: 45%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yerz2dg2/

Comment: did you try the answer before reply?

Comment: Yes i tryed. Its just aligned secont <td> tag to right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

**HTML Code**

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th col width="60">File Name</th>
    <th col width="20" colspan="2">Date Time</th> 
    <th col width="20">Size</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td col width="60">1.jpg</td>
    <td col width="10">18-02-2015</td>
    <td col width="10">18:32:54</td>
    <td col width="20">55Mb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include following property in table tag

> cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<!-- table elements --!>
</table>
```

Comment: Put my code into jsfiddle and you can check this code not working.

Comment: `<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> ` width="100%"

Comment: I just forgot the fact  that cellpadding and cellspacing become obsolete in HTML5.